# Supporting multiple databases with entity framework

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework

My client has an asp.net application - a product used my several customers. It connects to MSSQL database using good old ado.net and stored procedures. I am supposed to rewrite the application so that the application supports MySQL and Oracle in addition to MSSQL. I am supposed to use entity framework to do this. I am new to EF. So can any one guide me as to how this can be done? Where should I start?

Comment: I would question the fact that a customer tells a developer what tools he must use.

Comment: EF can be configured to support other databases via providers. I can't speak authoritatively on this but if this were truly necessary to do for my application I would look into providers for Oracle and MySQL from a company like [Devart](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/entityframework.html) instead of depending on the open source and free options. I suggest this because EF continues to evolve quickly and a company like Devart has a vested interest in keeping up with that change. A company like Oracle (owner of both MySQL and Oracle and a major MS competitor) may or may not have that incentive.